# How to get a 'last publish date' for an item

Tags: publishing

I am working in `Sitecore version 7.2` and I was wondering how to get a last publish date for an item.

I get that any item has date created and date updated but it does not have a property called date published.

So, in order to get a last published date for an item, is it safe to assume that the **`last updated date`** in the **`web database`** for that particular item is the date the item was last published? Or is there something more elegant?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create some custom code to have such a functionality, out of the box Sitecore doesn't have such a functionality.

You can create a template with two fields : Publishing Date and Publishing By.

Create your own class:

```cs
 public class UpdatePublishingStatistics : PublishItemProcessor
 {
    private const string PublishedFieldName = "__Published";
    private const string PublishedByFieldName = "__Published By";

    public override void Process(PublishItemContext context)
    {
        SetPublishingStatisticsFields(context);
    }

    private void SetPublishingStatisticsFields(PublishItemContext context)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context.PublishOptions, "context.PublishOptions");
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context.PublishOptions.SourceDatabase, "context.PublishOptions.SourceDatabase");
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context.PublishOptions.TargetDatabase, "context.PublishOptions.TargetDatabase");
        Assert.ArgumentCondition(!ID.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ItemId), "context.ItemId", "context.ItemId must be set!");
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context.User, "context.User");

        SetPublishingStatisticsFields(context.PublishOptions.SourceDatabase, context.ItemId, context.User.Name);
        SetPublishingStatisticsFields(context.PublishOptions.TargetDatabase, context.ItemId, context.User.Name);
    }

    private void SetPublishingStatisticsFields(Database database, ID itemId, string userName)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(database, "database");
        Item item = TryGetItem(database, itemId);

        if (HasPublishingStatisticsFields(item))
        {
            SetPublishingStatisticsFields(item, DateUtil.IsoNow, userName);
        }
    }

    private void SetPublishingStatisticsFields(Item item, string isoDateTime, string userName)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
        Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(isoDateTime, "isoDateTime");
        Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(userName, "userName");

        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            item.Editing.BeginEdit();
            item.Fields[PublishedFieldName].Value = DateUtil.IsoNow;
            item.Fields[PublishedByFieldName].Value = userName;
            item.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
    }

    private Item TryGetItem(Database database, ID itemId)
    {
        try
        {
            return database.Items[itemId];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(this.ToString(), ex, this);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static bool HasPublishingStatisticsFields(Item item)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
        return item.Fields[PublishedFieldName] != null
                && item.Fields[PublishedByFieldName] != null;
    }
}
```

Add your pipeline :

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
   <sitecore>
     <pipelines>
      <publishItem>
       <processor type="Sitecore.Sandbox.Pipelines.Publishing.UpdatePublishingStatistics, Sitecore.Sandbox"                     patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.UpdateStatistics, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </publishItem>
     </pipelines>
   </sitecore>
 </configuration>
```

All the informations you can find here :

https://sitecorejunkie.com/2013/01/26/who-just-published-that-log-publishing-statistics-in-the-sitecore-client/

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed explanation! I will definitely try that out!
Thanks again :)

Comment: I just copy/paste from that blogpost. Thanks to @SitecoreJunkie

Comment: @SitecoreJunkie - Thanks a lot to you too!

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answers for the sake of googling people of the future, in case the last date the item was saved will do for your purposes, you can use `Sitecore.Context.Item.Statistics.Updated`

Answer (score 1):

You can not assume that the `Updated` field in the web database is the last published date, as the `Updated` field changes on save rather than publish.

However as the `Updated` field in web database will only change when an item has been published, it may be suitable identifying when the published item has changed.

```
public DateTime? LastChangedDate(Item item)
{
    var webDatabase = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
    var publishedItem = webDatabase.GetItem(item.ID);

    if(publishedItem == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return publishedItem.Statistics.Updated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get that information out of the box. 
What you could do, is implement a bit of custom code to get the information you are looking for. 
While using code, the following can help you get your result:

```
Database.Properties.GetLastPublishDate(Database target, Language language)
```

From here you can decide what to do with it.

Comment: Thanks Dilyano for getting back. But wouldn't the code you have mentioned above give me the last publish date for a specific database?, which may or may not be the last publish date for a specific item. However, thanks a lot for the pointer :)