# Using End Edit Silent and Showing Updated Field Values

Tags: events

I have an event processor [similar to this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1863/1436). I was originally passing in `true` for the parameter `silent` to `Item.Editing.EndEdit(bool silent)`. I figured that this programmatic change wouldn't need to change things like the `updated by` field or anything else that should normally change when a content editor is editing an item. This ended up causing the value to not show up updated until a save even ran on that item again or the app pool refreshed.

Is there a way to use the silent parameter but have updated values show in the content editor right away? Is setting this parameter to true dangerous in any way if I expect two specific fields to be updated by my code and nothing else?

Answer (score 3):

Avoid setting `silent` to true. It'll cause all kinds of strange things. It looks like you're looking at setting `updateStatistics` to false:

`item.Editing.EndEdit(false, false);`