# How to check latest published item?

Tags: publishing, powershell

We would like to check latest published items from `master` database to `web` database within some timeframe using powershell script.

Tried : Statistics tab updated and created field values.

However it does not show correct result.

Comment: I think Sitecore doesn't add the published date information for an item, so it can be added using a custom code. Check this one. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/how-to-get-a-last-publish-date-for-an-item